# How can I use UIViewController and UIView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui, xcode11

I have tried integrating a custom UIViewController inside a Swift application but I could not integrate it with SwiftUI elements like Text(). I get this error: Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type. Should I rather use UIView instead of UIViewController?

Comment: The session you should have already checked out is called Session 231: Integrating SwiftUI. Please, show that you've actually *tried* to learn (or at the very least, searched here and/or online) this! https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/231/

Comment: Sorry for sounding snarky - my comment stays. But it *is* a paradigm change, I understand. So in the interests of being more constructive - watch the link I gave you, paying attention to everything *but* most of all one thing - even a `UIViewController` in `SwiftUI` is actually just a `View`. Or rather, *it's* root view is. I've successfully been using an `MTKView`, wrapped inside a view controller, as a Swift UI View - using delegates and accessing functions in it. But understand, the paradigm change means you *need* to learn Combine along with SwiftUI. There's about 6 WWDC sessions on this.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I’ve just watched it. Helped me out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`UIView`’s and `UIViewController`’s can be implemented in SwiftUI via their respective classes, `UIViewRepresentable` and `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

Apple’s SwiftUI tutorials go over this, and other ways to go about integrating UIKit into SwiftUI.

SwiftUI Tutorials: 
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/tutorials

Placing a UIView into SwiftUI using UIViewRepresentable: 
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views
^ see section 5, which uses MKMapView as the UIView

Interfacing with UIKit: 
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit

Sorry for the lack of code in my answer, I’m AFK right now. However, the best way to learn *is* to track down and figure things out yourself. Hope this helps!

**Update**

If you want to integrate SwiftUI into an existing UIKit application, look into using UIHostingController. It works like:

```
UIHostingController(rootView: MySwiftUIStruct())
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uihostingcontroller

It allows you to place SwiftUI content in a UIKit application as you would place a UIView or UIViewController in it.